# What is an Odious Word™?

Tags: pattern, knowledge, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Odious Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: A table of Odious and Not Odious Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Odious Words™,Not Odious Words™
Cabanas,Bungalows
Canvas,Linen
Chunky,Bulky
Embassy,Sector
Fuzzy,Fluffy
Iguana,Lizard
Ladybug,Beetle
Laudanum,Tincture
Oak,Elm
Quagga,Zebra
Rhumba,Samba
Rugby,Football
Thanks,Gratitude
Wumpus,Mugwump
```

<sub>P.S.: This is my first puzzle! Any feedback on its strengths and weaknesses is much appreciated.</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange™!

Comment: Iguanas and ladybugs aren't odious! :P

Comment: Since you asked for feedback: I guess the question score speaks for itself, but I also think it's a very nice first question! Well defined and fairly difficult to solve. Can't point out any weaknesses to be honest. Looking forward to seeing (and maybe even solving :P) more puzzles from you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An Odious Word™ is a word that

> when converted to the decimal ASCII-representation of each letter, only contains [odious numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odious_number), and no [evil numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_number).

A more detailed explanation:

> Convert each letter of the word to the decimal ASCII-represantion:
>  - If it has odious numbers only, it is odious.
>  - A word is thoroughly evil if it only contains evil numbers.
>  - If both of these cases don't apply, it is not odious (aka evil)
> Here's a list of the words displaying if a letter is odious or evil:
>
> ```
>  Odious Words™            Not Odious Words™
>
>  Cabanas  OOOOOOO         Bungalows   EOOOOEEEO
>
>  Canvas   OOOOOO          Linen       OEOEO
>
>  Chunky   OOOOOO          Bulky       EOEOO
>
>  Embassy  OOOOOOO         Sector      EEEEEE
>
>  Fuzzy    OOOOO           Fluffy      OEOEEO
>
>  Iguana   OOOOOO          Lizard      OEOOEO
>
>  Ladybug  OOOOOOO         Beetle      EEEEEE
>
>  Laudanum OOOOOOOO        Tincture    OEOEEOEE
>
>  Oak      OOO             Elm         OEO
>
>  Quagga   OOOOOO          Zebra       EEOEO
>
>  Rhumba   OOOOOO          Samba       EOOOO
>
>  Rugby    OOOOO           Football    OEEEOOEE
>
>  Thanks   OOOOOO          Gratitude   EEOEEEOOE
>
>  Wumpus   OOOOOO          Mugwump     EOOEOOO
> ```

Comment: I was typing up an answer when you posted this!  Great work.  I agree that Samba appears to be odious, unless having a NON-odious first letter is a requirement?

Comment: @TwoBitOperation I think so too. I updated my answer, since I also made some embarrassing mistakes in my list. Now I think it's clearly a requirement that the first letter must be evil for an odious word. (and for a thoroughly evil word the first letter must be odious). This is kind of confusing IMO, since `00000` would then be considered evil, but I guess it's not that easy to find reasonable words.

Comment: So, so close! Try analyzing the words exactly as I typed them, that is, the case is relevant.

Comment: @Phlarx Hm... I tried using arrays `A-z`, `a-Z` and `Aa-Zz`, but no results... The cheeky answer would be to just *"reverse the boolean value of the first letter"*, but that's certainly not what you want to hear :P I'm working on it, would be a shame if I fail at this part (for anyone who figured it out: feel free to post your own answer)

Comment: Does it help if I say that hyphenated words are automatically Not Odious, but phrases (two or more words separated by a space) can be Odious?

Comment: @Phlarx Yes, that helps! I'll update my answer in a second, no idea why I got so focused on the latin alphabet!

Comment: @LukasRotter You got it! Personally, I would call most words in the Not Odious column as neither odious nor evil, but there was nothing in the question to hint at that. Good job!